# How can I return value from a function to a variable declared before it (without global variables)?

Tags: python, function, variables, global-variables

The following does have the variable declared before the function however when printing the variable within the function the value desired is outputted however when printed after the function the value of the variable remains the same as it did when declared.

```
foo = 0
def method(bar, baz):
   foo = bar + baz
   print(foo)
   return foo
method(1, 3)
print(foo)
```

With the use of global variables the desired value is outputted however I would prefer an answer that does not contain global variables.

Comment: You never execute your function in the snippet you provide. Can you give a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: `foo = method(1, 3)`?

Comment: My apologies, a simple silly mistake made in the name of the function.

Comment: You are neither modifying the global `foo`, nor are you assigning the return value of the function to `foo`. You'll have to do one of the two.

Comment: You issue arises precisely because `foo` *is* a global variable. What do you mean by `an answer that does not contain global variables` when your question explicitly enforces one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure this is what you want, since strictly speaking you cannot have a global variable without having a global variable. What you can do is having a *mutable* global variable which you can modify without an explicit `global`.

```
foo = []  # list is mutable, just like dict, set, ...
def method(bar, baz):
  foo[:] = [bar + baz]  # replace foo's *elements* via [:]
  print(foo)
  return foo
method(1, 3)
print(foo)
```